# Insert data in sql with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to insert data in a sql table using ajax and php, but it's not working. My ajax give me the result like it works, but when i look at the table, there's not in it. Doing it without ajax works fine, so i guess my php is working ok.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<form action="servico.php?p=cadUsr" method="POST" id="frmCadUsr">
    Nome: <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="txtNome" id="txtNome"/>
    Idade: <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="txtIdade" id="txtIdade"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
    $passo = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";


    switch($passo){

        case "cadUsr":
            cadUsr();
        break;

        default:
            getRetorno();
        break;
    }

    function getRetorno(){
        echo "Este texto foi escrito via PHP";
    }

    function cadUsr(){
    require("dbCon.php");
    require("mdl_usuario.php");

        $usr = $_POST["txtNome"];
        $idade = $_POST["txtIdade"];

        $resultado = usuario_cadastrar($con,$usr,$idade);

            if($resultado){
                echo "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso";
            } else {
                echo "O cadastro falhou";
            }
    }
?>
```

OBS: I need to pass the action of the form with the url parameter as cadUsr, so it call the function in php.

AJAX:

```
window.onload = function(){

        var xmlhttp;
        var frm = document.querySelector("#frmCadUsr");
        var url = frm.getAttribute("action");
        var nm = document.querySelector("#txtNome").value;
        var idade = document.querySelector("#txtIdade").value;

        frm.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            try{
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }

                xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
                xmlhttp.send("txtNome=" + nm + "&txtIdade="+idade + "&p=cadUsr");

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        //alert("Deu certo");
                        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                }
            } catch(err){
                alert("Ocorreu um erro.<br />"+ err);
            }
        });
```

}

The PHP function to insert the data:

```
function usuario_cadastrar($conexao,$nome,$idade){


        if($nome == "" && $idade == ""){
            return false;
        }





        $sql = sprintf("insert into usuario (nome,idade) values ('%s',%s)",$nome,$idade);

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

            return $resultado;
    }
```

Comment: what do your browser tools tell you? If you sniff the request does it send params and are they filled?

Comment: `frm.addEventListener("submist",function(e){` at line 9, change `submist` to `submit`?

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi sorry, that was my mistake while putting the question here, it's right in my code and still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Mouser i think so, because with jQuery it works fine. I'm having this problem only using pure javascript.

Comment: @anuseranother what about line 17 `idade.value`, because you get the value itself in line 7

Comment: the form post request is enough to send the data ..ajax is not needed

Comment: You check if the is ready and status 200. It says nothing about saved data. Please post your sql full filled query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I think the  problem is here `servico.php?p=cadUsr`. You copy the `action`-attribute from the form with a querystring. If you cut the querystring from it, I think it will work.

The main problem is being called by Hossein:

This :

```
$passo = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";
```

Will not work. You're doing a post, you can't get `GET` variables.

You call `value` on `value` which will result in `undefined` and that will put no data in your database.

```
 xmlhttp.send("txtNome=" + nm + "&txtIdade="+idade + "&p=cadUsr");
```

So remove `value` and add the `cadUsr` variable to the querystring in the send function. Update PHP to:

```
$passo = (isset($_POST['p'])) ? $_POST['p'] : "";
```

And it will work!

You can see your callback codes by adding `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);` to your readystate success function.

Also you need to set the requestheader `content-type` to x-www-form-urlencoded when sending post.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, but i need the querystring `p=cadUsr` to call the php function !

Comment: Put it in the querystring of your send function!

Comment: ok, i edit the question and now you can see why i need top pass the querystring in the form and the function in php that make the sql query !

Comment: What you've said makes perfectly sense, but here we go. I tried to take-out the `querystring` from the form, and put the php function in the `default switch` value, and still don't worked. I added the `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);` like you said and it returned O cadastro falhou, that's the error in the php function. When i change the `_GET` to `_POST`, it give me "Este texto foi escrito via PHP".

Comment: But have you removed `.value` from `nm` and `idade`?

Comment: BTW, is there really a need to send the querystring "&p=cadUsr" in the send(), it i already insert into in the url open ?

Comment: You're doing a post. You're not allowed to send params through `open`. They need to be in the `send`. That's the way how it is designed.

Comment: Updated now, btw, i don't really think we need to change the _GET to _POST in $passo variable, because i just need to use the post in the form fields. Right ?

Comment: Yes, you must. Also do you know how to operate browser tool (F12) button? Remove `p=cadUsr` from the URL and update the get to post.

Comment: Ok, it is just like that ! And yes, i'm checking in the console, that's where i'm getting the results from the readystate success !

Comment: Also you must be able to see the result (answer/response) from the server in the network tab. What is PHP echoing back to the client?

Comment: It's "POST" and the file is "servico.php" type HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84900/discussion-between-mouser-and-anuseranother).